# Unable to get image data from toDataURL( ), Getting error SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using canvas to get image data, and i'm sending that image data to webservice, from there image will be decoded and callback coming is url of other domain, if i want to get the image data from that image, Its throwing error. Tried img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably then, the domain that the image is on is not set up to serve CORS-enabled images. You will need to find out how to do that on the "other" domain: http://enable-cors.org

At the bottom of that site is a form where you can check if CORS support is enabled correctly on the domain/image.

If you do not own the domain that the image is originating from, you're out of luck.